# GCloud Recommendations AI import catalog error

Tags: gcloud

No matter i was using GCloud console or command line, when tried to import
Merchant center's data from BigQuery, it shows

```
Import failed: Failed to fetch service account credentials for project:
xxxx. Importing from BQ will fail.
```

Comment: It's probably a good idea to post what you're trying to import so people can better understand what the error is.

Comment: oh, it was trying to import merchant center's product list from BigQuery

Comment: it solved after i started a new project to handle it